# is it possible to access ec2 instances with public ip when connected with aws client vpn

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn

I have setup of aws client vpn . my ec2 instance in a public subnet in same vpc which is connected with endpoint . client vpn is associated with target network (subnet) where ec2 instance is residing

I followed aws doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/what-is.html

I am able to access ec2 instances when connected with vpn with private IP on a rdp session . but there any solution to use public ip of instances to access them when connected on client vpn

Comment: Accessing instance via public IP is totally unrelated to having VPN. In fact, VPN is to VPC - not to individual instances. So, if you could access an instance without VPN; you can still access it after VPN is in place

Comment: yes, agree with that .  what made that question to ask is , we have a bamboo server connected with aws agents and it displays public IP of agents which is used by few DEV/QA folks to access the instances but when I move to client VPN setup , I should find a way to provide the IP address

Comment: If you access Public IP addresses via the VPN, the traffic would need to exit the VPC and then come back in again. This would probably ruin any security groups that were configured. You'd really need to use the private IP addresses.